# rails generate model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to follow instructions from the book "Head First Rails" and on page 50 it says to create a model but I am unable to create a model using the rails command.

When I type this at this prompt: localhost:~ home$

```
 rails generate model ad name:string description:text price:decimal seller_id:integer email:string img_url:string
```

I get this:

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /Users/home/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an application template (can be a filesystem path or URL)
      [--skip-gemfile]           # Don't create a Gemfile
      [--skip-bundle]            # Don't run bundle install
  -G, [--skip-git]               # Skip Git ignores and keeps
  -O, [--skip-active-record]     # Skip Active Record files
  -S, [--skip-sprockets]         # Skip Sprockets files
  -d, [--database=DATABASE]      # Preconfigure for selected database (options: mysql/oracle/postgresql/sqlite3/frontbase/ibm_db/sqlserver/jdbcmysql/jdbcsqlite3/jdbcpostgresql/jdbc)
                                 # Default: sqlite3
  -j, [--javascript=JAVASCRIPT]  # Preconfigure for selected JavaScript library
                                 # Default: jquery
  -J, [--skip-javascript]        # Skip JavaScript files
      [--dev]                    # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to your Rails checkout
      [--edge]                   # Setup the application with Gemfile pointing to Rails repository
  -T, [--skip-test-unit]         # Skip Test::Unit files
      [--old-style-hash]         # Force using old style hash (:foo => 'bar') on Ruby >= 1.9

Runtime options:
  -f, [--force]    # Overwrite files that already exist
  -p, [--pretend]  # Run but do not make any changes
  -q, [--quiet]    # Suppress status output
  -s, [--skip]     # Skip files that already exist

Rails options:
  -h, [--help]     # Show this help message and quit
  -v, [--version]  # Show Rails version number and quit

Description:
    The 'rails new' command creates a new Rails application with a default
    directory structure and configuration at the path you specify.

    You can specify extra command-line arguments to be used every time
    'rails new' runs in the .railsrc configuration file in your home directory.

    Note that the arguments specified in the .railsrc file don't affect the
    defaults values shown above in this help message.

Example:
    rails new ~/Code/Ruby/weblog

    This generates a skeletal Rails installation in ~/Code/Ruby/weblog.
    See the README in the newly created application to get going.
localhost:~ home$
```

I am using Rails -v 3.2.8
and Ruby 1.9.3p125

Comment: did you cd into your rails project dir?

Comment: I think that may be the problem. I have no project dir. The book is written for rails version 2.1 In this tutorial I was to create a directory using 'rails mebay' but that command does not work in Rails 3.2.8. I'm not supposed to use 'rails new mebay' because I'm supposed to manually create the models and controllers. I think there is a step missing in the book.

Comment: Style note: models should be capitalized, i.e. `ad` should be `Ad`.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The code is okay but you are in the wrong directory. You must run these commands inside your rails project-directory.

The normal way to get there from scratch is:

```
$ rails new PROJECT_NAME
$ cd PROJECT_NAME
$ rails generate model ad \
    name:string \ 
    description:text \
    price:decimal \
    seller_id:integer \
    email:string img_url:string
```

Comment: See this lesson was intended to show you how to manually create models and controllers. It says that using "rails new mebay" creates a scaffolded app, but a scaffolded app provides more than we need. So we are supposed to manually create the model first using "rails generate model ad blah:string". Except it doesn't tell us how to create the app directory first. I think there is a step missing in the book.

Comment: I'll try your suggestion above

Comment: The command `rails new mebay` doesn't generate a scaffold app. It only produces the skaleton of a rails-app. Without that, you cannot start to write your application.

Comment: Oh, ok. My mistake. I followed your steps and it seems to work. The book still misses a step explaining to do this first "rails new PROJECT_NAME". Thanks for your help!

Comment: An abbreviated version of this command is `rails g model ModelName column_name:string`

Answer (score 13):

The error shows you either didn't create the rails project yet or you're not in the rails project directory.

Suppose if you're working on myapp project. You've to  move to that project directory on your command line and then generate the model. Here are some steps you can refer.

Example: Assuming you didn't create the Rails app yet:

```
$> rails new myapp
$> cd myapp
```

Now  generate the model from your commandline.

```
$> rails generate model your_model_name
```

Answer (score 4):

For me what happened was that I generated the app with rails new rails new chapter_2
but the RVM --default had rails 4.0.2 gem, but my chapter_2 project use a new 
gemset with rails 3.2.16.

So when I ran

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

the console showed

```
Usage:
   rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

So I fixed the RVM and the gemset with the rails 3.2.16 gem , and then generated the app again 
then I executed

```
 rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

and it worked

Answer (score 2):

You need to create new rails application first. Run

```
rails new mebay
cd mebay
bundle install
rails generate model ...
```

And try to find Rails 3 tutorial, there are a lot of changes since 2.1 Guides (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) are good start point.