# Is it possible that the "rails new" command was aliased to just "rails"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, bash

I ran

```
rails new new_app
```

and the file created was called `new` rather than `new_app`. I ignored it, and moved on with a Rails tutorial. At some point, the tutorial wanted me to use rails scaffolding. When I ran

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

the help menu popped up. Instead of showing the help menu for generate or scaffold or just rails, the help menu was for `rails new APP_PATH [options]`. I then ran

```
rails -h
```

and the help menu for rails new popped up instead of just rails. This problem remains even after I uninstall and reinstall the rails gem. Is the issue something on my side? I was wondering if anyone knows the reason why this is happening, and how I might fix it.

Comment: You're not using the version of Rails you think you are. Rails 2 exhibited the `new` behaviour you're seeing.

Comment: Using Rails 4.0.0 not 2.

Answer (score 0):

Add to .bashrc

```
function ListAllCommands
{
    COMMANDS=`echo -n $PATH | xargs -d : -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 \
        -executable -type f -printf '%P\n'`
    ALIASES=`alias | cut -d '=' -f 1`
    echo "$COMMANDS"$'\n'"$ALIASES" | sort -u
}
```

see if you have `rails new` alias to `rails`

Comment: Ran the above function. Did not see an entry for rails new, but the entry for rails did not seem to have an alias attached to it. OUtput was:
...
rackup
radeontool
rails
rake 
rake1.9.1...

Comment: What do you get when you do `rails -v`

Answer (score 0):

For me what happened that I generate the app with rails new rails new chapter_2
but the RVM --default had rails 4.0.2 gem, but my chapter_2 project use a new 
gemset with rails 3.2.16.

So when I ran

```
rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

the console showed

```
Usage:
   rails new APP_PATH [options]
```

So I fixed the RVM and the gemset with the rails 3.2.16 gem , and generated the app again 
after that ran

```
 rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
```

and it worked

Visit [rails generate model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924526/rails-generate-model/21682115#21682115)