# Rails bin/rails generate model rails aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I tried running this code:

```
rails bin/rails generate model Article title:string text:text
```

But am getting:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'generate' (see --tasks)
bin/rails:4:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I am following the blog documentation line by line and completely installed the ruby but I am still confused; why it is not working?

Comment: try `rails g model Article title:string text:text`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you navigate to the App root directory and run

```
bin/rails generate model Article title:string text:text
```

or just

```
rails g model Article title:string text:text
```

[rails-generate](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate) - Rails docs

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is with `rails bin/rails`.

`rails` is the command. If it is not in the local directory, your computer will search the path to find the first instance of the program, which happens to be located at `bin/rails`.

Then you pass in the arguments `bin/rails generate model Article title:string text:text`.

Try removing the first argument so that the `generate` command is interpreted correctly by the program.

Your command should look like this after the edit: `rails generate model Article title:string text:text`.

For an example, please see this link: [Stack Overflow Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924526/rails-generate-model)